# Is there a way to watch for changes to a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a new Django application and would like to have functionality where one user makes a change and all other users viewing that database record receive the change.

I have seen similar functionality in frameworks like Derby and Meteor.  Is this even possible using Django?

Comment: Check signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: [django-notifications](https://github.com/pinax/django-notification) ?

Comment: While they are "viewing"? Are you talking real-time in here? Because that takes it to another level beyond Django, i.e. frontend work has to be done as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save your data, you should use signals.
If you wanna update data on changing instance in database, you can do it with web sockets.[socket.io](http://socket.io/)